# DrawerOpen in 'header' using StackNavigator and DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native

I want to use `DrawerOpen` in header using React Navigation. I is showing error "undefined is not an object(evaluating `this.props.navigation`)". I am using `StackNavigator` and `DrawerNavigator`.

Source: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/drawer.

Please help.

```
header:{
    right: <Button onPress={() => 
    this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
    title="Info" />
},

...
const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
    Dashboard: { screen: DashboardScreen },
    Chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
});

const App = DrawerNavigator({
  Stack1:{screen:SimpleApp},
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    title:'title',
    headerLeft: <Button title="button" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')} />
})
```